# iSH: LOOP gives "illegal hardware instruction"

Tags: assembly, x86, emulation

I'm running Linux via [iSH](https://ish.app/) on an iPad. I wrote a simple assembly program using LOOP, but executing it results in an “Illegal hardware instruction” on that opcode.

A manual `dec %ecx jnz label` works fine. Is this just a case of whatever emulator it’s using not bothering to implement LOOP because compilers don’t generally use it?

Comment: What is iSH; can you link a page about it?  It emulates x86, instead of the native AArch64 instruction-set of an iPad's CPU?

Comment: Looks like their x86 emulator might be incomplete.

Comment: Added link to app.

Comment: @fuz: I'm curious now how iSH works; its github issues page (https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues) has various reports of missing system-calls, which makes me wonder if it emulates Linux kernel APIs instead of emulating a full-system x86 running a real kernel.  But maybe for user-space it does just emulate?  The front page (https://github.com/ish-app/ish) mentions a "JIT" that threads together hand-written asm functions with an array of function-pointers.  So yeah, presumably its own custom x86 emulation code, not using existing stuff like Bochs or QEMU.

Comment: I looked at the [source](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/blob/master/emu/decode.h) a bit and it seems that `e0`, `e1`, and `e2`, (`loopne, loope, loop`) are just not in the Big Decoding Switch

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems to use emulation for code running in userland, but traps syscalls and translates them to their iPadOS equivalents at the level of complete calls. (I guess the alternative would be running the Linux kernel under the emulator and only reaching out to the real OS when it would normally hit hardware.)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  If it ran a real Linux kernel, it would have to emulate privileged instructions and the full x86 details like page tables, GDT/IDT, interrupt handlers, and all that.  It would take way more CPU time.  A middle ground would be running a paravirtualized Linux kernel with "drivers" that call into the host emulator but otherwise run natively in kernel mode.  But you'd still need more complicated stuff like network bridging which an iOS app might not even be able to do (can iOS apps inject raw network packets?)  Making user-space Linux sockets be iOS sockets avoids that.

Comment: I opened an issue/feature request: https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues/2174. 
Thanks, everyone, for the help tracking it down. @harold: make that an answer and I'll accept it.